# How to disable button if there is no data in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<input
                      :type="passwordFieldType"
                      v-model="user.password"
                      id="password"
                      name="password"
                      class="input-section-three-register"
                      value=""
                      placeholder="Enter new password"
                      autocomplete="off"
                       @change="disabledSubmit"
                    />
                    
  <input
                      :type="passwordFieldTypetwo"
                      v-model="user.confirmPassword"
                      id="confirmPassword"
                      name="confirmPassword"
                      placeholder="Confirm password"
                      value=""
                      autocomplete="off"
                      :disabled="user.password.length < 8"
                      @change="disabledSubmit"
                    />


 mounted() {
    this.disabledSubmit();
  },
```

```js
disabledSubmit() {
     this.disableButton = this.user.password.length<8 || 
         this.$v.user.password.$error ||
         this.user.password!==this.user.confirmPassword;
},
```

```html
<button
    type="submit"
    :disabled="disableButton"
> 
     pp
</button>
```

Issue  with the above code is, even without entering any data initially, I can proceed once I click on button. Only after I enter some data disable is working.

Comment: Please provide more code. Also, please check this [ask] Or even better, a [repro]

Comment: Make sure that `disableButton` either starts disabled or that you call `disabledSubmit()` sufficiently early

Comment: @mousetail for every input i have added  @change="disabledSubmit". and i am calling that inside of the method

Comment: @mousetail i have updated my code. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yea that's too late. You only update the button when the inputs are modified

Comment: @mousetail what can i change in my code, In order to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by completely removing the variable `this.disableButton`, instead, use a function:

```
getSubmitDisabled() {
     return this.user.password.length<8 || 
         this.$v.user.password.$error ||
         this.user.password!==this.user.confirmPassword; 
},
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<button :disabled="getSubmitDisabled()">
```